# Creating DataService for Quickbooks PHP API for Laravel

Tags: laravel, quickbooks-online

Good Day! so i was integrating Quickbooks PHP API, i finished installing the SDK via composer and i'm about to configure it

My question is where do i exactly put this code in Laravel

```
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;


// Prep Data Services
$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
     'auth_mode' => 'oauth2',
     'ClientID' => "Client ID from the app's keys tab",
     'ClientSecret' => "Client Secret from the app's keys tab",
     'RedirectURI' => "The redirect URI provided on the Redirect URIs part under keys tab",
     'scope' => "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting or com.intuit.quickbooks.payment",
     'baseUrl' => "Development/Production"
));
```

Thank you

Comment: What does DataService do? Can it be a singleton? You _could_ instantiate it inside a controller, however the "best" practice would be to use contextual binding to inject this configured instance into your controllers using dependency injection. If it can be a singleton then just create one so that all classes can consume the configured instance via dependency injection.

Comment: Honestly, i don't have any idea how to implement this it's my first time working on quickbooks api for my laravel app. the dataservice is from their documentation. https://intuit.github.io/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/configuration.html

Comment: It _looks_ ok to be a singleton, but if all that is going over your head then a singleton probably isn't the right fit for your skill level. For now, its fine for you to just instantiate it in you controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll try it right away

Comment: Did you ever figure out where to put it and do you have a repo link if do you did? I am just finishing off setting up a Laravel/Quickbook app and I just put it in my Controller as suggested above.